# Comparing IP's in a text file against html file

Tags: powershell

I have a text file which contains many IP's and I would like to compare it with a html file.

I have got some scripts in Powershell but the output does not contains the exactly IP but with the IP starting by the last octet.

```
$file1 = Get-Content H:\Downloads\hnames.txt
$file2 = Get-Content H:\Downloads\cpdb2web_B976151009_1\Outputs\test.html

$result = "H:\Downloads\names.txt"

$file1 | foreach {
    $match = $file2 -match $_
    if ( $match ) {
        $match | Out-File -Force $result -Append
    }
}
```

**hnames.txt (sample text file)**

```
10.66.94.16
```

**output.txt**

```
<a href="#network_object_Net_10.66.94.16_n28">Net_10.66.94.16_n28</a>
<a href="#network_object_Net_10.66.94.16_n28">Net_10.66.94.16_n28</a>
<td vAlign="top"><a name="network_object_Net_10.66.94.16_n28">Net_10.66.94.16_n28</a></td><td vAlign="top">
    </td><td vAlign="top">10.66.94.16<br>
    </td><td vAlign="top">10.66.94.168<br>
    </td><td vAlign="top">10.66.94.162<br>
    </td><td vAlign="top">10.66.94.164<br>
```

I tried another script but it is not working too,

```
$File1 = Get-Content H:\Downloads\hnames.txt
$File2 = Get-Content H:\Downloads\cpdb2web_B976151009_1\Outputs\test.html

$RegEx = "("
ForEach ($Line in $File1){
    $RegEx += "$Line|"
}

$RegEx = [regex]"$($RegEx.SubString(0,($RegEx.Length - 1))))"   #trim the last | out, we don't need it

$Search = $File2 | Select-String -Pattern $RegEx -AllMatches

ForEach($Match in $Search.Matches){
    Write-Output "$($Match.Value) was found in firewall"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, it would be great if you can show us a sample of `test.html` as well.

Comment: hi, it's an confidential file, but i can share you an example

Comment: When you share such details, edit it with dummy data, that's why I used the word **Sample**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed a little bit(not tested), use the `$_` instead of match as its the IPAddress that you want.

```
$file1 = Get-Content H:\Downloads\hnames.txt
$file2 = Get-Content H:\Downloads\cpdb2web_B976151009_1\Outputs\test.html

$result = "H:\Downloads\names.txt"

$file1 | Foreach-Object -Process {
    $match = $file2 -match $_
    if ( $match ) {
        $matches[0] | Out-File -Force $result -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not working, the names.txt contains the same ips than the hnames.txt even if this ip is not present in the html file

Comment: @Jerem Corrected the code to use `$matches` automatic variable.